# Attr disable won't disable my button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the following error:

I have a script that checks if 2 fields are the same, but the "register" button is clickable all time, whereas it should be un-clickable until all fields are like they should be.

My full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerModel_MemberProperties_0__Value').keyup(function () {
        checkpassword($('#registerModel_Password'), $(this));
    });

    $('#registerModel_Password').keyup(function () {
        checkpassword($(this), $('#registerModel_MemberProperties_0__Value'));
    });

    $('#registerModel_MemberProperties_0__Value').prop("type", "password").addClass("form-control")
    function checkpassword(password, confirmpassword) {
        var button = $('#Registerbutton');
        button.attr("disabled", false);
        if ($(password).val() == $(confirmpassword).val()) {
            button.attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            button.attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }
});
```

My code for the disable button:

```
button.attr("disabled", false);
```

HTML added:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <fieldset>
            @Html.ValidationSummary("registerModel", true)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => registerModel.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => registerModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => registerModel.Name)
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => registerModel.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => registerModel.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => registerModel.Email)
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(m => registerModel.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => registerModel.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => registerModel.Password)
            <br />
            @if (registerModel.MemberProperties != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < registerModel.MemberProperties.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Value, registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Name)

                    @Html.EditorFor(m => registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Value)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => registerModel.MemberProperties[i].Alias)
                    <br />
                }
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => registerModel.MemberTypeAlias)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => registerModel.RedirectUrl)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => registerModel.UsernameIsEmail)
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="Registerbutton">Sign up</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this `button.attr("disabled","disabled");`

Comment: please post you html

Comment: It's codede it umbraco but let me post that :) Added

Comment: `button.prop("disabled", true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#Registerbutton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/1thxsxcc/)

Comment: I see it works but in my script it doesen't diable it. hmmm

Answer (score 1):

`button.attr('disabled','disabled');` will do the work. If You want to remove The disable, `button.removeAttr('disabled');` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
 button.attr("disabled", false);
```

To this

```
button.prop("disabled", true);
```

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj6dtumg/1/)

Comment: `$(button)` means `$($('#Registerbutton'))`. That's wrong.

Comment: The reason can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538125/why-is-element-similar-to-element.

Answer (score 1):

Use .prop() instead of .attr()

```
$('#Registerbutton').prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
button.prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Allright i fixed it with this:

```
$('#Registerbutton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

What i needed to do was to function the button over my

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Then it worked!
Thanks for the help!